# PHP & Implementing .Netish Properties

Tags: php

I've decided to have some fun, and implement .Net Properties in PHP.

My current design centers around something like:

```
$var;

method Var($value = null)
{
if($value == null) {
return $var;
}
else {
$var = $value;
}

}
```

Obviously this runs into a bit of an issue if someone is trying to set the property (and associated variable) to null, so I am thinking of creating a throwaway class that would never be used. Thoughts, comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel. PHP already provides the magic methods [`__get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and [`__set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) that can be used to implement .NET-lookalike properties; there are examples on the documentation pages. PHP frameworks also use these hooks to redirect code execution to proper getter/setter methods (which really need to be distinct, for the reason you have discovered yourself) so that read-only properties can be achieved as well; an (admittedly complicated) example is [this](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/base/CComponent.php#95).

Pro tip: if you do override `__get` and `__set`, you will need to also override `__isset` and `__unset` so that your class can continue to behave intuitively in the presence of constructs such as `empty` and `unset`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want a getter?

```
public function getVar() {
    return $this->var;
}
```

Do you want a setter?

```
public function setVar($newVar) {
    $this->var = $newVar;
}
```

You can even make it public and have someone on the outside to set the var:

```
public $var;
...
$object->var = "New Var";
```